# How to log to reporting services from winforms application

Tags: windows, winforms, authentication, reporting-services, ntlm

**Situation:**
I have a windows forms application. It uses webbrowser component to display web application.
On this web application, there is an iframe, which contains and displays report from Reporting Services (MS SSRS).

When I display the page(from windows forms app's webbrowser component) containing this iframe with report - Windows ntlm authentication prompts asking for username and password.

I need to authenticate the user programmatically from this winform app by using credentials - username and password - from config and Windows Authentication(the ntlm window) must not promt.

Any Ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: To authenticate the user automatically you should use `ReportViewer` instead of `WebBrowser`.

Comment: Hello Reza. Thank you for idea. My problem is, that the iframe with report is a part of an application, which is written in java. With my winforms webbrowser component, I am displaying this application. I cannot use ReportViewer there. :-(

Comment: But as you said, that web application uses SSRS and so it has a report server url and each report has a report url, It seems you can use those urls to pass credential and show your reports in ReportViewer in your windows forms application. I think that java application has no role in your solution to show report, report viewer will use reprort server and reports urls.

Comment: I see where are you aiming. I will try this. Your advice is much appreciated. Thank you.